# How to launch workers on AWS EC2 instance when running locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, julia, distributed-computing

I have put together a distributed setup at my university using the `Distributed` package that comes with Julia for running some intensive simulations. I usually launch workers on local machines through ssh using [addprocs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Distributed/index.html).

I have launched an c5.24xlarge EC2 instance. The aws_key.pem file exists and I have done

```
chmod 400 aws_key.pem
```

I am able to ssh into the instance just fine.

I am trying to add workers with the following code

```
workervec2 = [("ubuntu@ec2-xxxx:22", 24)]
addprocs(workervec2 ; sshflags="-i aws_key.pem", 
         tunnel=true, exename="/home/ubuntu/julia-1.0.4/bin/julia", 
         dir="/home/ubuntu/simulator")
```

I am trying to add additional workers on my Amazon EC2 instances, but I am failing with the following error

```
Warning: Identity file  aws_key.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
ubuntu@ec2-xxxx: Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: LoadError: Unable to read host:port string from worker. Launch command exited with error?
```

The warning comes even when launching workers on the local machines, but the launch goes through. However, launching on my EC2 instance fails with the following error, while I am able to ssh from the terminal. What is going wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Adding the ssh key from my local machine to the EC2 instance did the trick. [This](https://mikeeverhart.net/2013/05/adding-an-ssh-key-to-amazon-ec2/) helped.

Then, workers can be added as usual

```
workervec2 = [("ubuntu@ec2-xxxx:22", 24)]
addprocs(workervec2 ; sshflags="-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub", 
     tunnel=true, exename="/home/ubuntu/julia-1.0.4/bin/julia", 
     dir="/home/ubuntu/simulator")
```

Comment: putting ssh credentials directly on instances is not usually a good idea, consider ssh key forwarding